# Running Phantomjs.exe in a ASP.NET Core in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, phantomjs, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ReSTful API implemented in .Net Core 2.0.0 and hosted in an App Service in Azure.

I am trying to get one of the Controllers to generate a PDF file using PhantomJS.exe

so I have created this method

summary of the controller is

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = config.pjlocation;
        pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = ....; //argument
        pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //not diplay a windows
        pProcess.Start();
        output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //The output result
        pProcess.WaitForExit();
```

this works well when I run my controller locally using

```
dotnet run
```

on a windows machine with the same version of .Net Core as the one azure uses.

But hitting the API when deployed to azure, the service fails to produce any response for a long time and comes back with this error

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process.

the only place I found some traces is the live log stream in azure where a HTML gets dumped into console by azure

> HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway The specified CGI application
>   encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

What is happening here and has anyone encountered similar issue? How can I further debug?

[image: error]

Comment: Note that I have already checked that all paths resolve correctly. I get meaningful errors if paths are incorrect.

Comment: Have you checked the Azure level logs? They can be found in the Azure portal. Have you added application insights? This can really help with debugging, too.

Comment: Deploy to App Service with Linux workers instead (bring your own container). The Windows flavor of App Service doesn't allow you to bind to an arbitrary port, which is what PhantomJS tries to do and fails - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

Comment: @evilSnobu switch to Linux seems to be too much effort and risky. I would probably try the other pdf generator claimed to be supported. ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the answer from [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks), **PhantomJS** is **not supported** on the Azure WebApp.

> Other scenarios that are **not supported**:
>
> **PhantomJS**/Selenium: tries to connect to local address, and also uses **GDI+**.

According to the [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks), The following PDF generators are supported. If WebApp is not the only choose, you could refer to [Azure cloudservie or Azure VM.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm)

> SQL Reporting framework: requires the site to run in Basic or higher (not that this currently does not work Functions apps)
>
> **EVOPDF**: See http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx for vendor solution
>
> Telerik reporting: requires the site to run in Basic or higher. More info here
>
> Rotativa / wkhtmltopdf: requires the site to run in **Basic or higher.**
>
> NReco PdfGenerator (wkhtmltopdf): requires subscription plan **Basic or higher**